# python get all submodules without having to define __all__

Tags: python

My requirement might be a bit strange, but here it is:

I have a package called `handlers`. Outside of this package, I have `main.py`. In `main.py`, I need to get all the submodules under `handlers`. Now I can define `__all__` in `__init__.py` but that would have to be updated everytime I add a new submodule in the directory. So is there a way to automatically keep `__all__` updated?

Comment: That's not what `__all__` is for.

Comment: `__all__` **limits** what is being imported from a module. It does *not* expand it.

Answer (score -1):

You need to [explicitly state](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) where you're getting the modules from in `main.py`.

Even if it becomes 50+ lines after constant updating, so be it. [Don't use the `from handlers import *` notation](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-best-practices-for-using-import-in-a-module).